# How to use terminal ssh login almost automatically

Tags: ssh

I have been using terminal and ssh. But I can connect to many people as I have a school where everyone has a mac and I'm able to connect to them. But I want to create a file in nano and when I run it it will do ssh user@ipadr but I want instead of that I want it to ask for the ip-address and username on a different line like Ip-address: and Username: then I type it in and it will connect when I fill that out.

ps: I know ununtu is probably different but I need help quick.

Comment: I fail to see the point. Is typing an `@` so hard? If you want, set an alias: `alias sshl='ssh -l '`. Then you can do: `sshl user ip`.

Comment: The nano will save the file so I won't be able to add the username/ipaddress so I need the file to ask me for the username/ipaddress so I can use the same file for any remote host i want. When the file runs it will run what it's told and I will want to be able to manually add the username/ipaddress as it runs.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: No I just want to be able to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't be too hard with a couple of `read` prompts:

```
#! /bin/bash
read -p 'Username: ' user
read -p 'IP: ' ip

ssh "$user"@"$ip"
```

Comment: @ChadMcMillin please [accept](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer if you found it useful

Comment: I dont know how